# how to use datetime in sails model

Tags: node.js, datetime, model, sails.js, waterline

i would like to have a function in my controller to get data based on time range. First, i have all the data in mongodb, there is a attribute ModifiedTime as string looks like `2015-02-25T17:17:33Z`. Second, i define the model in sails with ModifiedTime:

```
{ type: 'datetime', columnName: 'ModifiedTime' }
```

In the model.js, I set `schema: true`. Then in my controller, i try to use

```
 User.find({ModifiedTime : {'<=' : new Date('2015-03-18T00:00:00Z')}}).exec(function(err,st){
      if (err) return res(err);
          if (!st) return res(new Error('Invalid ModifiedTime.'));

          return res.json(st);
    } );
```

But i get nothing, see always [] in the browse. I used waterline http://localhost:1337/User to check the data in browse. i can see all the data from mongodb. The strange thing is, i see something like `ModifiedTime": "2015-02-18T17:36:53Z`. so, for me, it looks like the ModifiedTime in sails is still a string, am i right? but i set the type as datetime in the model. I hope, it could transfer the string of mongodb to datetime in background, won't it? Please give some advise. i spend already too much time for that :(
thank you very much!
WJS

Answer (score 0):

You're right / wrong.

In your DB you state the datetime is a string. If it is already a string then you can't set it to be a  date in your sails model. You should simply compare two strings instead of transforming `2015-03-18T00:00:00Z` into a date.

```
 User.find({ModifiedTime : {'<=' : '2015-03-18T00:00:00Z'}}).exec(function(err,st){
      if (err) return res(err);
          if (!st) return res(new Error('Invalid ModifiedTime.'));

          return res.json(st);
    } );
```

If you truley want to use Date/Time then you must go through your original data and change modified time to a date/time object.

Comment: Hi Meeker, thank you very much for the hint. ok, i think the easiest way is to compare string. just for further understanding. i saw "datetime check if string in this record looks like a javascript datetime" in this link https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md   what does this Validation Rules mean? is there an easy way to tranform by that? just interesting to know :) thank you

Comment: Your welcome! You can validate as a date and keep it as a string if you wish. {type:string',date:true} - this should do what you want. You just can't use {type:date} because your current dates are strings. Answer your question?

Comment: Hi Meeker, yes, i got it. i have just tried your idea, but i always get throw error: TypeError: object is not a function.    by calling the function. where could be the problem? thank you

Comment: the strange thing is, if i change the '<=' to '!' it works without error. but you know, that is not what i need. so, anything wrong by using '<=' ?

Comment: Sorry, you can try 'datetime', the documentation says that date need to be an date object where as datetime simply needs to look the part.

Comment: thank you Meeker, i have tried datetime, unfortunately the same. but i see something very strange. as i described before, if i use '!' or '==', it doesn't throw error, but i always get [], even when i tried with the same string! but if i use '<=', it throws error. So, i believe that it have something to do with the finding results. but what could it be? no idea :(

Comment: sorry, i correct something in the last comment: if i use '!', i get all the data from database, it's correct. if i use '==' and test with the same string, i get []. but if i use {ModifiedTime  : '2015-03-18T00:00:00Z'} instead, i get the right data which is matching. so, there is a bit different there. At last, if i use '<=', i get a error. that is really strange. maybe anyone have an idea, what could it be? thank you

Comment: i did some more test. i tried '<=' with number, it works fine. but with string not, also by other attribute. so, it seems that there is problem by using '<=' with string. what shall i do then?

Comment: can you go ahead an re-post your full model the way it is now and the query your trying to run and sample data your trying to run it against. You might put it in a gist or something. I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi Meeker, no problem.

Comment: I have found your issue. as a string the sails-mongo adapter wants to translate that into regex which does not work for greater than or less than queries. You have some options, you can either use the Model.native() to query your data or you need to turn all those ModifiedTime attributes into dates and then update your model so that type = date. Or you can take a look at my pull request here that fixes your issue. https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/pull/251

Comment: great! i think i will try to get the latest sails-monge... thank you!